# Cocos2dx : Deleting kinematic bodies once they are off screen

Tags: c++, cocos2d-iphone, box2d, cocos2d-x

I am trying to build a platform game. In my game, random platforms appear and move from right part of the screen to the left part .

```
Using :
b2Vec2 impulse = b2Vec2(-5, 0);
platformBody->SetLinearVelocity(impulse);
```

But when I see my stats, the number of call / countRef (First line of the Stats) is always increasing as the new platforms move from right to the left. I want to know how can I remove the existing platforms once they have moved passed the left screen (off screen). All my platforms are b2_kinematic bodies (Box2D).

**EDIT ANSWER :**

I managed to solve it through the following :

> for(std::vector::size_type i = 0; i != m_platforms.size(); i++)
>
> {
>
> ```
>   if (m_platforms[i]->GetPosition().x < 0.0f && m_platforms[i]->GetType() == b2_kinematicBody) 
>
>     {
>
>       CCSprite *sprite = (CCSprite *) m_platforms[i]->GetUserData();
>
>       sprite->removeFromParentAndCleanup(true);
>
>       world->DestroyBody(m_platforms[i]);
>
>     }
> }
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check whether or not your bodies are out of screen on the main loop, and destroy them if so. Something like.-

```
if (platformBody->GetPosition().x < SCREEN_X_LIMIT) {
    world->DestroyBody(platformBody);
    // Also, remove attached sprite if exists
}
```

Comment: Yes I know that :) . But the problem is I have put the LinearVelocity on the kinematic body (platform). Now what I have done is, I call a function after 10 seconds and I keep all the platform bodies in an array. After 10 seconds I check if the platform has moved offscreen, delete its body (like the above code) and its sprite. But still the referenceCount (the first line of displayStats()) is only growing instead of decreasing periodically which means that the bodies are not getting released from memory. After sometime as the count grows the game FPS gets lower and the game is slow. Please help

Comment: Mmh, not sure, but I'm guessing it may have something to do with keeping the bodies in that array. Are you removing the bodies references from the array? I'd suggest iterating through all world bodies instead of having a separate array for platforms.

Comment: I am not sure if iterating through all the world bodies would help, because there are other bodies (ground, hero etc) which I want to keep at all times, I just want to remove only platforms that are not visible anymore. I'll try checking my code again and will let you know if I am doing anything wrong.

Comment: Sure, but you could check offscreen condition only for kinematic bodies for instance, or have a tag in your sprites (assuming you have assigned them to bodies `userData`) that indicates whether or not they should be removed.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions .. I have updated my question with the answer